# How to effectively use box.new() to plot between buy & sell signals

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am using the box.new() to highlight the the % gain from a buy signal to a sell signal.

A few problems arise.

1. Box.new() starts the plot on a Buy signal but continues to plot until the most recent bar even after a sell signal appears.
2. The function I use to calculate the % gain calculates to the last bar instead of Buy signal to sell signal.

[box.new() continues even after sell signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lidcy.png)

3. I would like to have each box.new() appear between a buy to sell signals and with the option to have a box between a sell to buy.

[Multiple box.new() stacked on the recent signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YUAh.png)

---

The issues of the code I am having are below. The actual indicator portion to show buy, sell, stoploss and trendchanging are all working great. Portion regarding box.new() are shown below.

---

```
// Input button to toggle the visibility of the percentGainBox
var bool useBox = input.bool(true, title="Show % Gain", group="Plot Settings")

// Define coordinates for percentGainBox
var float boxLeft = na
var float boxBottom = na
var float boxRight = na
var float boxTop = na

if Buy and trendChanged
    // Set box coordinates based on recent Buy signal
    boxLeft := bar_index
    boxBottom := close

if Sell and trendChanged
    // Update right limit of the box if there's a Sell signal
    boxRight := bar_index
    boxTop := close

// If there's no Sell signal, continue box to last bar
if na(Sell)
    boxRight := bar_index
    boxTop := close

// Calculate percentage gain
var float percentageGain = na
if not na(boxBottom) and not na(boxTop)
    percentageGain := (boxTop - boxBottom) / boxBottom * 100

// Determine box background color based on percentageGain
var color boxColor = na
var color borderColor = na

if percentageGain >= 0
    boxColor := color.new(color.lime, 90)
    borderColor := color.lime
else
    boxColor := color.new(color.maroon, 90)
    borderColor := color.maroon

// Create percentGainBox based on the value of useBox
var box percentGainBox = na
if useBox
    percentGainBox := box.new(left = int(boxLeft), top = close, right = int(boxRight), bottom = int(boxBottom), border_color = borderColor, border_width = 1, 
         border_style = line.style_solid, bgcolor = boxColor, text = "% Gain: " + str.tostring(percentageGain, "#.##") + "%", text_size = size.normal, text_color = color.white, text_halign = text.align_center, text_valign = text.align_top,
         text_wrap = text.wrap_auto)

// Plot Signals    
plotshape(Buy and trendChanged, style=shape.labelup, title='Buy', location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.lime, 55), text='Buy', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
plotshape(Sell and trendChanged, style=shape.labeldown, title='Sell', location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.maroon, 35),text='Sell', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
```

---

I have tried to modify the code several times. And the best I could come up with was deleting previous boxes to only show the current box.

```
// Create percentGainBox based on the value of useBox
var box percentGainBox = na
if useBox
    percentGainBox := box.new(left = int(boxLeft), top = close, right = int(boxRight), bottom = int(boxBottom), border_color = borderColor, border_width = 1, 
         border_style = line.style_solid, bgcolor = boxColor, text = "% Gain: " + str.tostring(percentageGain, "#.##") + "%", text_size = size.normal, text_color = color.white, text_halign = text.align_center, text_valign = text.align_top,
         text_wrap = text.wrap_auto)

    // Delete previous percentGainBox
    box.delete(percentGainBox[1])
```

[One Box only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq34J.png)

The result of the addition of box.delete(percentGainBox[1]) is shown above.

Ideally I would like to have boxes plotting between the buy and sell signals with the % gain / loss.

[Ideal Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpZmf.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. My preferred way would be to use a UDT like so. You'll need to adjust some style parameters since I use a light background but I believe this is the result you're looking for

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

type gBox 
    bool active = true
    box b
    box gainBox
    float g 

var boxes = array.new<gBox>()

useBox = input.bool(true)
buy     = ta.crossover(ta.ema(close,5),ta.sma(close,10))
sell    = ta.crossunder(ta.ema(close,5),ta.sma(close,10))

if buy
    boxes.unshift(gBox.new(true, b = box.new(bar_index, close, bar_index + 1, close, border_color = color.new(color.white,100))))

if boxes.size() > 0
    for b in boxes
        if b.active 
            b.g := (close - b.b.get_bottom()) / b.b.get_bottom() * 100
            b.b.set_bgcolor(b.g > 0 ? color.new(color.green,80) : color.new(color.red,80))
            b.b.set_border_color(b.g >= 0 ? color.lime : color.maroon)
            b.b.set_right(bar_index)
            b.b.set_top(close)
            if na(b.gainBox) and useBox
                b.gainBox := box.new(b.b.get_left(),b.b.get_bottom(),bar_index,close,color.new(color.white,100), bgcolor = color.new(color.white,100), 
                     text_color = color.black, text_valign = text.align_top, text_size = size.normal)
            if not na(b.gainBox)
                b.gainBox.set_text('% Gain: ' + str.tostring(b.g,'#.##') + '%')
                b.gainBox.set_right(bar_index)
                b.gainBox.set_top(close)
        if sell
            b.active := false
```

[image: boxes]

Comment: This is my first time using stack overflow, so if I am responding to an answer by providing more details is wrong then I apologize. I edited the post in hopes it would help.

Comment: that worked, but best way is to just add to your question